# How can I check which Gradle Android plugin version is used in my project?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

In my build.gradle file I set the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
```

This will automatically adapt to the latest released version (like it's described [here](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)).

How can I check which current release is used in my project?

**EDIT 2013-08-08:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the Gradle release, it's the Gradle Android plugin version. If you want to know the Gradle release, run `gradle -v`.

Comment: Ok, I need to know which gradle android version is used. Sorry, that I interchanged the things. To stay correct, I changed the title again.

Comment: Is this `dependencies` block contained in a `buildscript` block?

Comment: Yes it is. I add this block in my answer above.

Comment: I realize this was asked a long time ago, so you likely haven't thought about it. Gradle has introduced a direct way to get this, so the currently accepted answer is no longer the best answer... Time to change your selection?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Showing the resolved dependencies for the build script class path isn't a built-in operation as for other configurations (which can be inspected with `gradle dependencies`). However, you can write a task to do so. For example:

```
task showClasspath  {
    doLast {
        buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { println it.name }
    }
}
```

A variation that just shows the Android plugin version:

```
task showVersion {
    doLast {
        println buildscript.configurations.classpath.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.moduleVersion
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also remove the `.name` to print the full path of the jars, which is helpful it there are multiple jars with the same name (eg I have several instances of gradle-x.x.x.jar from different plugins): `buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { println it }`

Comment: This is no longer true. See my response below. 'buildEnvironment' was added around Gradle 3.0. Accepted answer should be updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 24):

Newer versions of Gradle (3.0+, and possibly earlier) support a built-in `buildEnvironment` task that shows the dependency graph for buildscript.

`./gradlew buildEnvironment`

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_buildscript_dependencies

Answer (score 8):

> To determine what revision of the plugin you are using, check the version declaration in the project-level `build.gradle` file.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
```

In the above example, the Gradle Android plugin version/revision is 1.3.0

Comment: How to get this version programmatically in gradle script?

Comment: The OP is using a dynamic version, and wants to know exactly which version is being resolved. build.gradle only shows 0.5+. Wants to know if it's 0.5.1, 0.5.12 or something else.

Answer (score 4):

try the following code:

```
com.android.builder.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION
```

This is the easiest one I think.

Comment: `com.android.builder.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION` has been removed now, we can use `com.android.builder.model.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION` instead

Comment: Even `com.android.Version` now.