# Gradle connectedAndroidTest returning error

Tags: android, testing, gradle

I am having trouble with the latest update to the android gradle plugin (19.0.3)! I am unable to get our tests to run on a library project anymore on our CI server. Either I am doing something wrong or the new version broke testing library projects.

I am attempting to run the tests from the command line:

```
./gradlew :libproject:connectedAndroidTest
```

When I run this on my local machine the tests run perfectly.

However, when I run it on our CI server I get this warning:

```
WARNING: support for libraries with same package name is deprecated and will be removed in 1.0
```

And then I get this error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/domain/lib/BuildConfig;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I believe this may be because the testPackageName is the same as the library package.

However if I change the testPackageName then no tests are found because the `<instrumentation>` tag in the generated manifest is incorrect. The androidTargetPackage points to testPackageName which no longer matches the library. Is there a way to set the `<manifest> package` in the generated AndroidManifest.xml that I am missing? The [docs don't seem to think it is required.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing-Android-Libraries)

Both builds generate two BuildConfig.java files in subproject/build/source which are identical on both machines:

```
$ find source -name "BuildConfig.java"
source/buildConfig/debug/com/domain/lib/BuildConfig.java
source/buildConfig/test/debug/com/domain/lib/BuildConfig.java
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why it works on my local machine and not on our CI server. Versions of Gradle are the same except for the java version:

```
./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_25 (Oracle Corporation 23.25-b01)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.8.5 x86_64


$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 24.45-b08)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.8.5 x86_64
```

The build.gradle file at the root of the repo:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

The build.gradle in the subproject:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':testrunner')

    // Test Dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0',
            'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0',
            'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5',
            'com.google.mockwebserver:mockwebserver:20130706'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
    enforceUniquePackageName=false

    defaultConfig {
        testPackageName "com.domain.lib"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.domain.testrunner.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        testHandleProfiling true
        testFunctionalTest true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

I have also done `android update -u -a` on both machines to ensure the tools are all the same and everything possible is installed.

I am at my wits end on this one! I can't figure out what is different. Help me Stack Overflow, you are my only hope!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your test package is set to `com.domain.lib` which is also the package name of your library. This is not correct, as it collides with the library name.

You should just avoid using `testPackageName` as you probably don't care what the test app package name is anyway. If you leave it blank, it'll automatically create one based on the library's package name + `.test`

I see you are using `enforceUniquePackageName` but this is to enforce it between library dependencies. We will add a check for this (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67338).

You could also disable the packaging of the BuildConfig but they would may run into other problems, so it's really just better to not set a package name on the test app.

Comment: Having the tests and the library in the same package is allowed with the current two project setup under Eclipse.

When I take out testPackageName then the targetPackage on the `<instrumentation>` tag is set as "com.domain.lib.test" and none of the tests are found. The tests are not in that package. Do the test have to be in a com.domain.lib.test package with the new gradle build?

Comment: No the tests do not have to be in that package to be found.

Comment: I misunderstood about the tests not being found because gradle is producing libproject/build/reports with zero tests showing. Using showVersion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098231/how-can-i-check-which-gradle-android-plugin-version-is-used-in-my-project I see my dev machine is on 0.9.0 and CI is on 0.9.1 hence the difference in behavior.

Comment: Updating the root build.gradle to specify `dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.1'
    }` makes the behavior consistent. Thanks for the help.