# How to list available plugins in Gradle

Tags: gradle

Is there any way to list available plugins in gradle? Like `gradle tasks --all` for plugins? If not, how do I get plugins from gradle project model?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There's no such task that lists all the plugins applied to project. However [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginAware.html#getPlugins()) method may be helpful.

```groovy
project.plugins.each {
   println it
}
```

Comment: You can extend `println it` to `println "${it} -> ${it.getClass().location}"` to also get a path to an actual jar containing the plugin. It can help to figure our which plugin version is in use.

Answer (score 11):

As a complement to the accepted answer, one could also do as [recommended in this answer by Peter Niederwieser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18119304/816017)

```
task showClasspath {
    doLast {
        buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { println it.name }
    }
}
```

Which will show JAR names of the classpath dependencies, as well as the version of the jar.

Comment: Except it prints nothing. On my machine, using Gradle 6.5.1.

Answer (score 4):

The list of plugins can be found in the properties of root project, via `gradle properties`.
We can parse this information from the command-line using PowerShell:

```bsh
gradle properties | 
    Where-Object { $_ -match '(?<=^plugins: \[).*(?=\])'; } | 
    Out-Null; 
$Matches.Values -split ", " | 
    ForEach-Object { ($_ -split "@")[0]; }
```

I ran this command on my Spring Boot project using Gradle 6.7 and Powershell 7.1.0 and got the following output:

```
org.gradle.api.plugins.HelpTasksPlugin
org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.BuildInitPlugin
org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.WrapperPlugin
org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin
org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.JvmEcosystemPlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.ReportingBasePlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin$Inject
org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaLibraryPlugin
org.gradle.api.distribution.plugins.DistributionPlugin
org.gradle.api.plugins.ApplicationPlugin
```