# Where and how to add classpath dependencies in gradle 7.2?

Tags: android, gradle

For android project created with gradle 7.2, the **project gradle** is very different from the previous ones, it now only contains these

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The **settings.gradle** is also very different from before, it now contains more configurations with the following

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My App"
include ':app'
```

Where can I add the classpath for `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'`? When I add this to the settings.gradle, it fails to compile with error: "Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler"

Answer (score 12):

I think with gradle version 7.2 you don't really need to specify the classpath, check [doc1](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/plugins.html), [doc2](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/use/PluginDependenciesSpec.html). Just insert plugin id on project level build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.10" apply false
}
```

and don't forget to copy-paste it on app level build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}
```

To check if the plugin is applied correctly, you can print the list of available plugins from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31051313/9846834).

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_plugins_buildscript   Example 13. Applying a plugin with the buildscript block

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
```

Answer (score 1):

paste code for your build-script class file in project-level gradle.build file, here is an example :

```
/**
 * project-level - build.gradle file -- make sure buildscript is before 
 * plugins
**/
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.41'
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.20' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add setting.gradle like this

```
   dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://android-sdk.tapdaq.com" }
    }
    }
    rootProject.name = "App Name"
    include ':app'
```

buils.gradle(project level)

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.10"
ext.kotlincoroutine_version = '1.5.1'
ext.coroutineadapter_version = '0.9.2'
ext.gradle_version = '3.5.0'
ext.retrofit_version = '2.9.0'
ext.gson_version = '2.8.7'
ext.okhttp_version = '4.9.0'
ext.glide_version = '4.12.0'

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}
```