# New format build.gradle?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I used to connect the plugin OneSignal like this
[image]

How connect the plugin in new format with plugins?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where and how to add classpath dependencies in gradle 7.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610025/where-and-how-to-add-classpath-dependencies-in-gradle-7-2)

Comment: Please check documentations https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup .They have properly mention about latest versions.

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb sorry, but I don't see information for new version gradle

Comment: @Sky for OneSignal don't work

Comment: @СергейГуков As per document-
Newer versions of Android Studio
 When creating a new project from Android Studio Artic Fox (or newer) the allprojects{...} is no longer added in the project level gradle. You should only copy the buildscript portion of the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71911256/9846834) and one signal [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup) we can do that:

```
plugins {  // Project level
    ...
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.14.0' apply false
}
```

then:

```
plugins { // App/Module level
    ...
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.7.3")
}
```

And lastly refer to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051235/how-to-list-available-plugins-in-gradle/31051313#31051313) we can check all applied plugins: [image]

FYI [OneSignal Gradle Plugin releases](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/releases), [OneSignal
Android SDK releases](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases)