# How can I determine the Android Gradle plugin version in use from within my own Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, plugins

## Context

I'm writing a Gradle plugin for Android projects. My plugin relies on some methods from the Android Gradle plugin, but the exact calls I need to use have changed as the Android Gradle plugin has evolved (e.g. the methods I need are different in v2.1.2 vs v2.2.2 of the Android Gradle plugin). I want to get the Android Gradle plugin version programmatically from within my own plugin, and then invoke the appropriate methods for that version.

## Question

How can I access the Android Gradle plugin version programmatically from within my own Gradle plugin? Is calling

```
project.rootProject.buildscript.getDependencies()
```

the right starting point?

Comment: @stkent: Have you tried [anything based on this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18119304/115145)?

Comment: @CommonsWare that seems to apply when you want to access the plugin dependency versions; this question is about the Android Gradle plugin version which seems like it should be available independently of any specific configuration evaluation?

Comment: @stkent: "that seems to apply when you want to access the plugin dependency versions" -- that would seem to be what you want, though. However, I do not know what Gradle considers "buildscript configurations" to mean.

Answer (score 5):

```
def version = com.android.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION
```

And for old Android Gradle plugin versions (now deprecated):

```
def version = com.android.builder.model.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION
```

Answer (score -1):

You can obtain a Gradle instance by calling `Project.getGradle()`, then invoke `gradle.gradleVersion` to get the current Gradle version!

Maybe it can help you!

Comment: This method just to get the gradle version but not the android plugin for gradle.  There are different! https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html